# how to translate or localize material-ui (MUI) 5 DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

[image]

in material ui 5 i want to change text of ok and cancel button
how can I do that
seems like there is no option.

in Material-Ui 4 this was possible with these props:

```
okLabel="تأیید"
cancelLabel="لغو"
clearLabel="پاک کردن"
```

this is my code:

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali}>
              <DatePicker
                displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
                closeOnSelect={true}
                label="تاریخ:"
                mask="____/__/__"
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                views={["year", "month", "day"]}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField {...params} />
                )}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

this is the documentation:
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#main-content

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same behaviour with some setting `localeText` on LocalizationProvider component. So your example will look something like this:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali} localeText={{ cancelButtonLabel: "لغو", okButtonLabel: "تأیید", clearButtonLabel: "پاک کردن" }}>
  ...
</LocalizationProvider>
```